# use case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to use case statement in where clause in sql server and get the error message.

```
WHERE (PRCA.EDLType = 'E')
AND 
(
 NOT 
 (
  PRCA.EDLCode IN
  (
   SELECT EarnCode
   FROM dbo.udECforUnionRpt
   WHERE (EDL = 'E')
  )
 )
) 
AND (PRCM.udMasterCraft IS NOT NULL) 
AND (PRCA.PREndDate BETWEEN @BegPREndDate AND @EndPREndDate)
AND PRCM.udMasterCraft BETWEEN @BegMasterCraft AND @EndMasterCraft  
AND PRCA.Class BETWEEN  @BegClass AND  @EndClass 
AND 
 (
  CASE WHEN @ExcludePREAPR='Y' THEN UPPER(PRCA.Class) not like upper('%PREAPR%') 
  else PRCA.Class
 ) 
 END
)
ORDER BY PRCA.PRCo
```

maybe because the PRCA.Class have two condition? or i just do not write CASE Statement right.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure z_UPSPRUnion_test, Line 82
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'.

Answer (score 3):

Dump the case statement.  Use this:

```
AND (UPPER(PRCA.CLASS) not like '%PREAPR%' OR @ExcludePREAPR != 'Y')
```

Comment: Finaly i use the if begin end and run two seperate select clause. But finilly it works. thank for your help.